# Zend Framework 2 autoloading

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-autoloader

I am just starting to look at Zend Framework 2 (and am new to ZF in general), and in the [user guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/modules.html), they are using autoloading when adding a new module. However, I find the explanation to be quite challenging for a rookie. They are adding a `Module.php` file within the module directory, which among others contains the following code:

```
public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
                __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
            ),
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
```

Now I did some digging around to try and figure out what this autoloading is all about. As far as I understand, the autoloading uses `spl_autoload_register()` and is a way to avoid having `require_once()` everywhere in the code. So, when trying to use a class that is not defined, the `autoload()` method that was registered will be run, which simply does an array lookup and includes the file like below if it was added.

```
// Zend/Loader/ClassMapAutoloader.php
public function autoload($class)
{
    if (isset($this->map[$class])) {
        require_once $this->map[$class];
    }
}
```

This seems clever due to performance. I hope what I just wrote is correct. Based on this, I am trying to figure out what is going on in `getAutoloaderConfig()` from the first code snippet, but I am quite confused. It seems as if the array that is returned by this method is used for `AutoloaderFactory::factory()`, but I am not sure for what purpose. Instantiating autoloaders with options it seems, but exactly what that does, I am not sure. I guess the second entry of the array specifies where to find the source files for the module's namespace - at least that would be my guess. The first entry I am, however, not sure about. In the user guide, it says the following:

> As we are in development, we don’t need to load ﬁles via the classmap,
>   so we provide an empty array for the classmap autoloader.

The file just returns an empty array. I am not sure what the purpose of this ClassMapAutoloader.

Sorry if my point is unclear; basically I am trying to figure out what is happening in `getAutoloaderConfig()` and what `mymodule/autoload_classmap.php` is used for. If someone could shed some light on this, that would be much appreciated!

Comment: Zend is so over engineered its ridiculous.

Comment: Absolutely. But I think that if you find your way around it, it's actually really powerful. Like Magento.

Comment: I use it at work, it has it's ups and downs.  I prefer Kohana though, and use whatever Zend Libraries I may need.  Sorry @andy124, haven't used 2 yet, sorry to hijack your question.

Comment: ZF2 is a totally different animal from ZF1, at least when using it as an application. Not sure if I like it yet, but I'm trying to learn it.

Comment: @wes Don't worry about it. I actually agree with you, even though I am still new to it. The learning curve feels like climbing Mount Everest, especially with ZF2. ZF1 seemed simpler, even though it had its flaws. My initial impression of ZF2 is that someone was thinking "hey, this would be super cool" instead of keeping things simpler. There is nothing wrong with aiming for perfection and professional development, but it just seems as if there was a radical change from ZF1 to ZF2 in regards to how easy it is to work with. That being said, I do enjoy the focus on modules in ZF2 and namespaces.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The classmap is there to show PHP the most direct way to a class. It's essentially saying "You you're looking for `A\Class\Youre\Looking\For`, look no further than this file: `xyz.php`. This would be expressed like this:

```
return array(
    'A\Class\Youre\Looking\For' => ___DIR__.'/xyz.php'
)
```

Without it PHP has to run through the whole autoloader chain, which can be pretty expensive. Why is it saying something about "as we're in development"? Because classmap files are typically generated on the production server by some script. Basically, just don't worry about it too much right now. It's micro-optimization...

The `getAutoloaderConfig()` method is just there to give you some flexibility in really advanced applications. Most of the time you can just use the SkeletonApplication's and SkeletonModule's boilerplate code and leave it alone. Really, you can even kill the `'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(__DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',)` part for now.

It's just a hook for future improvements and nothing to worry about too much if you're just starting out with ZF2 (like me ;).

Comment: Thank you. What you wrote about the ClassMapAutoloader makes sense in your example, but I am not certain why the key in the array is `Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader`. The value refers to a PHP file that is not even a class; it just returns an array. My guess would be that it's telling the `ClassMapAutoloader` to look in that file for configuration of the class map. Not that I will use it right now, but is the purpose of `autoload_classmap.php` then to just return an array of class names as key and path as value? As I understand from your answer, this is not necessary, but just an optimization.

Comment: Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader is a class. See https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Loader/ClassMapAutoloader.php
So it's saying "use the ClassMapAutoloader and give it the file autoload_classmap.php as a parameter". The autoloader then uses the returned array from that file to map classes to specific files.
Is that a little clearer?

Answer (score 8):

ZF2 has a number of autoloaders available.

The 2 most common (or the 2 which developers interact with directly at any rate) are `Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader` and `Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader`.

1. The classmap autoloader is usually used at the module level to
   provide a simple but fast array lookup mechanism.  It is configured
   with an associative array of `key => value` pairs, with the key
   representing the class, and the value representing the filename
   which defines the class.
2. The standard autoloader, on the other hand, is designed to hold a
   list of "namespaces" and base directories.  What is does is to then
   build the path to the class referenced, but not yet loaded, by
   prepending the base directory path for that namespace to the class
   name, to arrive at the final absolute path to the class file, which
   it then tries to include.  You can quickly populate the
   classmap_autoload.php file by running either
   `/path/to/ZF2/bin/classmap_generator.php` or `zftool.phar` generate
   classmap.

`Zend\Loader\AutoloaderFactory` is designed to manage the various autoloaders, and to make sure there are no conflicts.  Ultimately, of course, all autoloading capabilities leverage PHP SPL autoloading.

The purpose of `getAutoloaderConfig()` is to identify to the autoloader factory which autoloaders are available for this module's namespace.

In the example shown above, that would be, in order of preference, the classmap autoloader, followed by the standard autoloader.  If you don't wish to use the classmap autoloader for that module, simple remove the reference from the array returned by `getAutoloaderConfig()`.

The method name `getAutoloaderConfig()` is reserved.  If this method is defined, during the module initialization process, a listener (`Zend\ModuleManager\AutoloaderListener`) is attached which retrieves the configuration returned by this method, and adds it to the consolidated configuration.

Answer (score 3):

A web application consists of many PHP classes, and
each class typically resides in a separate file. This introduces
the need of *including* the files.

As your application grows in size, it may be difficult to include
each needed file. Zend Framework 2 itself consists of hundreds of files,
and it can be very difficult to load the entire library and all its 
dependencies this way. Moreover, when executing the resulting code, PHP interpreter will 
take CPU time to process each included file, even if you don't create an 
instance of its class.

To fix this problem, in PHP 5.1, the class autoloading feature has been introduced.
The PHP function `spl_autoload_register()` allows you to register 
an *autoloader* function. For complex web sites, you even can create
several autoloader functions, which are chained in a stack.

During script execution, if PHP interpreter encounters a class name 
which has not been defined yet, it calls all the registered autoloader functions
in turn, until either the autoloader function includes the class or "not found" error is
raised. This allows for "lazy" loading, when PHP interpreter processes the class
definition only at the moment of class invocation, when it is really needed.

Because each library's vendor uses its own code naming and file organization conventions,
you will have to register a different custom autoloader function per each dependent library,
which is rather annoying (and actually this is an unneeded work). To resolve this problem, 
the PSR-0 standard was introduced.

The [PSR-0 standard](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md)
(PSR stands for PHP Standards Recommendation)
defines the recommended code structure that an application or library must follow
to guarantee autoloader interoperability.

Each module of the web application registers an autoloader, which makes it possible to autoload
any PHP class in your modules. This is made with the `getAutoloaderConfig()` method of the `Module` class.

ZF2 has a special component named `Zend\Loader`, which contains implementations
of the two commonly-used autoloader classes: the standard autoloader (`Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader`)
and class map autoloader (`Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader`).

The fact that ZF2-based application modules conform to PSR-0 standard makes it possible to use the standard autoloader.

The class map autoloader can be used as a faster replacement for the standard autoloader.
This autoloader expects you to pass it a class map array. Each *key=>value* pair of the class
map is, respectively, the class name and path to the PHP file containing the class.

The concept of autoloading in Zend Framework 2 is well explained in [Using Zend Framework 2](https://leanpub.com/using-zend-framework-2) book.